# Vibration/Beep before Activity killed in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I'd like to explicitly terminate my activity after all the work is done, so I use:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

I also want to notify user by vibrating/beeping beforehand, so the codes look like:

```
beep();
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

The problem is that Android seems to cache the beep action until the whole activity is processed. In this case, the activity is force closed so that the beep action is actually never executed, so I never hear the sound.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Killing the process seems a bit extreme. Have you tried using `Activity.finish()`?

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

You could use,

```
((Activity)getContext()).finish();
```

instead of using Process.killProcess(). I've personally used it, and the activity termination seemed to be smooth. Since, you're killing the process, while you're still in it, you're getting the force close.

Hope this solves your problem!!